# How to translate a delegate event from C # to Kotlin that wants 2 input and 1 output parameters?

Tags: c#, kotlin, events, delegates, porting

I am porting a library from c # to kotlin and inside a class I have a delegate event which has 2 input parameters and one output parameter

```
public delegate bool MyDelegate(int para1, int param2)

public event MyDelegate IsFinished
```

this event is also called within a function of the class that defined it

```
if(IsFinished){
//do somethings
}
```

All this, in kotlin, how could I translate it?

Actually,I tried to create a class that simulates the event

```
class EventTwoReturnBoolean<T, U> {

    private val observers = mutableSetOf<(T, U) -> Boolean>()

    operator fun plusAssign(observer: (T, U) -> Boolean) {
        observers.add(observer)
    }

    operator fun minusAssign(observer: (T, U) -> Boolean) {
        observers.remove(observer)
    }

    operator fun invoke(value: T, value2: U) : Boolean {
        var bool : Boolean = true
        for (observer in observers){
            bool = observer(value, value2)
        }
            return bool
    }

}
```

can it be a valid solution?

Comment: it tells you that your question was a _bad fit_ for stackoverflow (and thus, most likely, will *not* receive any answers), and links to articles that tell you how you could improve your question. _which you didn't read_. but thank you for editing your question to include what you have tried. that edit actually _did_ improve your question. (also: my comment wasn't intended to maky anyone laugh.)

Comment: @Sweeper why do you think it would not be valid c # code?
I'm trying to port a C # library that is used to communicate with pos with ZVT protocol (in use in Germany)

Comment: @AdamoBranz It's missing some semicolons and you are not raising the event correctly (not sure if that's what you want to do). Anyway, "can it be a valid solution?" is not answerable unless you specify what features of C# events you need.

Comment: @Sweeper forget about the semicolons which are not important in this context.
Probably the person who wrote the library created a delegate to make the declaration of the event easier and made the observer of that event return a boolean value that he uses inside a function

Comment: Looks like some variation of EventHandler pattern (where delegate returns a value). But you're not returning a list of invocation results from observers, only the result from the last observer. Have they launched asynchronously in C#?

Comment: Yes, in my code I actually take only the last one, but I assumed there was one and only one observer, actually seeing the code better no one observes it so I can do without it.
The call was synchronous

Comment: If you know this observer at the moment of your publisher creation, you may use Kotlin's [observable property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#observable-properties) feature. Just declare an event as a property of `class CustomEventArgs(val param1: Int, val param2: Int)` type, and reset its value to raise an event.

Answer (score 4):

C# has build-in support for the EventHandler pattern. This is a variation of [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which allows the subject (*publisher* in EventHandler terminology) to have several observed states (*events* in EventHandler terminology). Also, it explicitly extracts arguments of the observer's (*subscriber* in EventHandler terminology) *event handler* method into the separate entity, passing reference to the *publisher* alongside it.

In C# it's implemented on language ([`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) and [`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=net-5.0) keywords) and stdlib levels ([`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-5.0) and [`EventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventargs?view=net-5.0) classes), while Kotlin doesn't provide this feature. However, it's possible to recreate exactly the same API in Kotlin (subscription/unsubscription via `+=`/`-=`, event raise via `()`).

Actually, you're trying to implement some variation of the EventHandler pattern (where delegate returns a value). I'll show, how to implement the classical EventHandler pattern in Kotlin, probably it will help you to implement yours.

First of all, we need to define the same basic classes:

```kotlin
interface EventArgs

typealias Observer<T> = (sender: Any, eventArgs: T) -> Unit

//In C# EventHandler subscription/unsubscription is thread-safe, so we need to keep it this way in Kotlin too
//Variant 1 - pure Kotlin, thread-safety is lock-based
class EventHandler<T : EventArgs> {
    private val subscribers = mutableSetOf<Observer<T>>()

    operator fun plusAssign(subscriber: Observer<T>) {
        synchronized(subscribers) { subscribers.add(subscriber) }
    }

    operator fun minusAssign(observer: Observer<T>) {
        synchronized(subscribers) { subscribers.remove(observer) }
    }

    operator fun invoke(publisher: Any, args: T) {
        subscribers.forEach { it.invoke(publisher, args) }
    }
}

//Variant 2 - JVM-specific, but more multihread-performant
class EventHandler<T : EventArgs> {
    private val subscribers = CopyOnWriteArraySet<Observer<T>>()

    operator fun plusAssign(subscriber: Observer<T>) {
        subscribers.add(subscriber)
    }

    operator fun minusAssign(observer: Observer<T>) {
        subscribers.remove(observer)
    }

    operator fun invoke(publisher: Any, args: T) {
        subscribers.forEach { it.invoke(publisher, args) }
    }
}
```

Here is a direct translation into Kotlin of basic [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines#example) from Microsoft's official "Publish events based on the EventHandler pattern" programming guide:

```kotlin
// Define a class to hold custom event info
class CustomEventArgs(var message: String) : EventArgs

// Class that publishes an event
open class Publisher {
    // Declare the event using EventHandler<T>
    val raiseCustomEvent = EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>()

    fun doSomething() {
        // Write some code that does something useful here
        // then raise the event. You can also raise an event
        // before you execute a block of code.
        onRaiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs("Event triggered"))
    }

    // Wrap event invocations inside a protected method
    // to allow derived classes to override the event invocation behavior
    protected fun onRaiseCustomEvent(e: CustomEventArgs) {
        //In this Kotlin implementation raiseCustomEvent is always non-null, even if there are no subscribers,
        // so all that actions to avoid NPE in C# implementation are redundant here

        // Format the string to send inside the CustomEventArgs parameter
        e.message += " at ${Instant.now()}" // pure Kotlin alternative - `Clock.System.now()` using https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime library
        // Call to raise the event.
        raiseCustomEvent(this, e)
    }
}

//Class that subscribes to an event
class Subscriber(val id: String, pub: Publisher) {
    init {
        // Subscribe to the event
        pub.raiseCustomEvent += ::handleCustomEvent
    }

    // Define what actions to take when the event is raised.
    fun handleCustomEvent(sender: Any, e: CustomEventArgs) {
        println("$id received this message: ${e.message}");
    }
}

fun main() {
    val pub = Publisher()
    val sub1 = Subscriber("sub1", pub)
    val sub2 = Subscriber("sub2", pub)

    // Call the method that raises the event
    pub.doSomething()

    // Keep the console window open
    println("Press any key to continue...")
    readLine()
}
```

The main flaw here is that the `invoke` method of `EventHandler` could be invoked in Kotlin from everywhere (in C# it can only be invoked from within the class that declared it):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val pub = Publisher()
    pub.raiseCustomEvent(pub, CustomEventArgs("Oops!"))
}
```

To fulfill this contract, `EventHandler` declaration needs to be changed (`invoke` method needs to become `protected` and class itself - `abstract`, because instantiating it directly won't make sense now):

```kotlin
abstract class EventHandler<T : EventArgs> {
    private val subscribers = mutableSetOf<Observer<T>>()

    operator fun plusAssign(subscriber: Observer<T>) {
        synchronized(subscribers) { subscribers.add(subscriber) }
    }

    operator fun minusAssign(observer: Observer<T>) {
        synchronized(subscribers) { subscribers.remove(observer) }
    }

    protected operator fun invoke(publisher: Any, args: T) {
        subscribers.forEach { it.invoke(publisher, args) }
    }
}
```

Event declaration will become a boilerplate:

```kotlin
open class Publisher {
    // Declare the event using EventHandler<T>
//- val raiseCustomEvent = EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>()

    //Declare backing property, extending EventHandler<T> and thus having access to its protected members
    private val _raiseCustomEvent = object : EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>() {
        operator fun invoke(args: CustomEventArgs) = super.invoke(this@Publisher, args)
    }

    // Declare the event referencing backing property
    val raiseCustomEvent get() = _raiseCustomEvent

    //Define public invoke operator extension in the scope of the Publisher class
    //Can't access raiseCustomEvent directly - it will lead to recursive problem (StackOverflowError in runtime)
    // that's why we need backing property
    operator fun EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>.invoke(args: CustomEventArgs) = _raiseCustomEvent.invoke(args)
}
```

Although event raise will become a bit cleaner:

```kotlin
//- raiseCustomEvent(this, e)
    raiseCustomEvent(e)
```

Now event could be raised only in the scope of `Publisher`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val pub = Publisher()
    pub.raiseCustomEvent(pub, CustomEventArgs("Oops!")) //Won't compile
    pub.raiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs("Oops!")) //Won't compile too
}
```

Probably, boilerplate could be reduced via code-generation based on annotation processing, but that's out of my answer's scope

Comment: Your EventHandler class is similar to my EventTwoReturnBoolean, the problem is that in the code I had to translate the event wanted to output a boolean, which for example your EventHandler class does not

Comment: Yes, the return type of event handler is hardcoded as `Unit`, if you want to make it more general, add another generic parameter to `EventHandler` and `Observer` indicating the resulting type of this call.